# AC_CANONICAL_HOST autoconf macro is generated outside if conditional in AS_IF

Tags: autoconf

I'd like to include in an autotools based project our new machine type, which is not recognized by autoconf macro AC_CANONICAL_HOST (other platforms still need to be treated with it). So I added AS_IF macro to handle it:

`AS_IF([test "x$host" == xtachy-linux-gnu], [SET_TACHY], [AC_CANONICAL_HOST])`

However, AC_CANONICAL_HOST generated output in *configure* file is located before *if* conditional. When I replaced AC_CANONICAL_HOST to anything reasonable, let's say

`AS_IF([test "x$host" == xtachy-linux-gnu], [SET_TACHY], [AC_MSG_NOTICE([TACHY_FALSE])])`

it works correctly and *if* conditionial in *configure* looks fine. Is there any problem placing with AC_CANONICAL_HOST macro in AS_IF?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is behaving exactly as it's intended to — `AS_IF` is part of the M4sh language that ensures that macro requirements are expanded unconditionally, rather than within a branch. Without this, for example, if the first `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` was in a conditional branch, and the second was unconditional, the latter will fail if the former branch was not executed.

`AC_CANONICAL_HOST` is not meant to be made conditional, which is why you see the expansion happening outside of your `AS_IF`.